# On Android, how do I grant a LiveFolders the required permission of my ContentProvider?

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

On Android, for a content provider that requires the FINE_LOCATION permission, how do I create a LiveFolder?

```
<provider 
   android:authorities="gpstracker" 
   android:name=".db.GPStrackingProvider" 
   android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</provider>
```

The LiveFolder keeps crashing in the at `com.android.launcher.LiveFolderAdapter.query(LiveFolderAdapter.java:58)` from a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`.

I keep on searching on how to grant the LiveFolder permission, but am unable to find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thing Android being Open Source and all. Not making much headway with granting the LiveFolderAdapter permission I checked out which permission it already had. LiveFolders is a part of the Launcher package. This is in the Android source in `packages/apps/Launcher/AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

From there I figured that the com.android.launcher.permission pretty much singles out the Launcher. I ended up requiring the launcher.permission for the LiveFolders of my contentprovider.

```
<provider 
   android:authorities="gpstracker" 
   android:name=".db.GPStrackingProvider" 
   android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
     <path-permission android:path="/live_folders/tracks"
     android:readPermission="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
</provider>
```

Got the endresult in my project at [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/AndroidManifest.xml).